# Finding repeating <br>'s between a certain <span>

Tags: java, android, regex

I have the following HTML string:

```
<span class='together'>line one,<br><span class='indent'>line two.</span><br>Line three,<br><span class='indent'>line four,<br>line five,<br>line six,<br>line seven;<br>line eight.<br>Line nine;<br>line ten,<br>line eleven,<br>line twelve.</span><br>Line thriteen,<br><span class='indent'>line fourteen,<br>line fifteen,<br>line sixteen,<br>line seventeen,<br>line eighteen.</span></span>
```

I am trying to find a regex expression that will find all the `<br>`'s that are between the `<span class='indent'>` and it's closing `</span>`. The `<span class='together'>` encapsulates the whole sting and should just be ignored.

At the moment the best I can do is: `<span class='indent'>.*?(<br>).*?<\/span>` which doesn't work at all. The first `<br>` this grabs is outside of the `<span>` and then it skips over a bunch of other `<br>`'s that I want ([See here](https://regex101.com/r/kX3oB3/1)).

Is this possible? Should I instead use `<span class='indent'>(.*?)\<\/span>` and then parse the captured group later?

As you can tell my regex knowledge is pretty limited.

Comment: In general, don't use regex to parse HTML, use a parser.

Comment: [**DON'T PARSE HTML WITH REGEX**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: That was quick. Thanks for that link @JonathonReinhart :)

Comment: @hjpotter92 this in Java for an android app. I'm getting this content from a JSON dump and then trying to put the (formatted) string in a TextView. The Html.fromHtml ignores spans and I don't think you can add your own styles to a textview to pick up spans.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Thanks. I'll check out XPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comments of other answer you wrote

> The content between the spans will only have a `<br>` tag in it and no other HTML...

If there are only `<br>` tags / no other tags before `<span class='indent'>` try with a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehind). There's only finite repitition allowed so need to set a limit to what max length inside the span could be.

```
(?s)(?<=<span class='indent'>(?:(?!</?span).){0,9999}?)<br>
```

Just picked 9999, you might need higher value depending on input. [Demo at regexplanet](http://fiddle.re/h487h6) (click Java).
`(?!</?span).` The negative lookahead is used to not skip a span when looking behind.

This only works for data like your sample and not with any nested spans. Use parser in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your work bobble bubble. I'm marking this as the correct answer as it does do what I asked. However a parser might be the "correct" way to solve my issue. In fact I ended up using regex to find the contents of my indent span and then did a some simple finding and replacing dealing with the <br>'s

Comment: You're welcome @Ampers, thank you! Sounds like you found the optimal way to deal with it. Well if parser or regex - I think it depends on the problem and if parsing arbitrary html or your own.